# Build docker image for mysql and asp net core. Issues with connection to database

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core

I am creating mysql in that way:

> docker run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e
> MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest

Here is my Dockerfile:

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build WORKDIR /source COPY .
> . RUN dotnet restore "./app/app.csproj" --disable-parallel RUN dotnet
> publish "./app/app.csproj" -c release -o /app --no-restore
>
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 WORKDIR /app COPY
> --from=build /app ./
>
> EXPOSE 5000
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]

And I build image in that way:

> docker build --rm -t dev/app:latest .

Next I run container in this way:

> docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 -e
> ASPNETCORE=HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
> --network=host dev/app

If I have --network=host I am able to connect to my database. But I don't have access to API from my browser.
API work if I don't using --network=host but in that way I can't connect to mysql and i got error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

The only thing I want to achieve is for my service to connect to the docker database and to have access to the API and swagger.

Comment: Did you use localhost:3306 as the MySQL server host and port? Many clients have the habit to use the UNIX socket then. Try to set a different port for the server container and the client.

Comment: @KlausD. my connection string:
"server=host.docker.internal;port=3306;database=db;uid=root;pwd=root;" I also tried
server=localhost

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually refers to the current container.  I've linked this question to two others: the 'via "hostname"' one describes how to create a Docker network so that the `docker run --name` container name `mysql` is usable as a host name, and the "connect to SQL server" one describes how to configure the application to use that name.  You do not need host networking for most applications, and you shouldn't need to call out to the host just to reach another container.

Comment: mysql didn't work for me, but when I set server=172.17.0.2 it work.